# tkinter Treeview is placing mysql data into one column

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, treeview

so I have looked around for days and tried various solutions to other people issues that seem the same as my own but unfortunately I have not made any progress. I am still very new with python, tkinter, and mysqli databases. What I trying to do is have an inventory program, it's just that simple. You can login and add, delete or simply view what is in the database. I can add and delete items just fine but I am having an issue pulling the data in the correct columns.

So far I have tried to pull each as a variable and assign it accordingly, tried to pull one row at a time, even switch to a new database but have gotten no correct results. If I use sqlite 3 it works fine so is it because mysql is on a server and not local? Any way, I'd like some advice to point me in the right direction so any help is much appreciated. [image: This is what happens when I run the program]
Edit:

```
 tree.insert("", 1, "dirIso", text="ProductID")
for n, dirIso in enumerate(results,1):
    list_of_column_values = [list(_dict.values())[0] for _dict in dirIso]
    tree.insert('dirIso', n, text=list_of_column_values[0],
                values=list_of_column_values[1:])
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

This is what I have done, I am now getting a 'str' object has no attribute 'values'. Do I need to change n? Or is it looking for the name inside of my database as values and not the columns?

Outcome I'm trying to get is for the table to display its respective data for each item.

Comment: Read this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53120798/7414759), how to get `dict` into a `Treeview`.

Comment: I have tried the way you suggested in the answer but I am getting "'str' object has no attribute 'values'". I have changed a few things around to try and fix it but have not gotten too far. Am I missing something?

Comment: [Edit] your Question, **remove ALL** code, except the function whith the `.insert(...` . Show your **last uses** version"

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: Treeview is placing mysql data into one column

---

**Edit** your Question, showing three rows of `results` data, if your `results` does not look like the following.

> Assuming the following `results` == `list` of `dict`!
>
> ```
>  results = [{'produkt_id': '1234', 'Name': 'John', 'Address': 'NewYork'},
>             {'produkt_id': '5678', 'Name': 'Peter', 'Address': 'Boston'}
>            ]
> ```

You didn't need **Tree Heading**, as you want a **Tabelview**

```
# Dict's are unordered, 
# therfore you need a list of fieldnames in your desired order
fieldnames = ['produkt_id', 'Name', 'Address']

# Loop results
for n, _dict in enumerate(results,1):
    # Create a list of values from this _dict
    _list = []
    for key in fieldnames:
        _list.append(_dict[key])

    # The first value goes to 'text'
    # All others goes to 'values'
    tree.insert('', 'end', n, text=_list[0], values=_list[1:])
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> 1234  John     NewYork
> 5678  Peter    Boston
> ```